# What's the best approach to execute two programs at the same time in C?

Tags: c, unix, fork, exec

I have two programs, A and B that run in unix. Both with the same priority. Both need to be executed at the same time. My question is, would it be better to run them from a third program (C) which executes A and B or should I run program A and executed B within A?

In any case what approach should I use exec() calls or should I use forks....?

Comment: If on Linux, read first [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then later [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). BTW "best approach" is by definition a matter of opinion. Read also a good [Pthreads tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). See [pthreads(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) and [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)

Comment: For non-Linux Unix like systems such as [FreeBSD](https://freebsd.org/) refer to their documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different approaches can be used. A possible solution would be a program of its own, which simply executes program a and program b using fork/execlp/waitpid.

It could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main() {
    pid_t pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) { //child 1 = a
        execlp("./a", "./a", NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "execution of a failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (pid1 > 0) { //parent
        pid_t pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == 0) { //child 2 = b
            execlp("./b", "./b", NULL);
            fprintf(stderr, "execution of b failed\n");
        } else if (pid2 > 0) { //parent
            int status1;
            if(waitpid(pid1, &status1, 0) == -1) {
                perror("waitpid for a failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            int status2;
            if(waitpid(pid2, &status2, 0) == -1) {
                perror("waitpid for b failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if(WIFEXITED(status1)) {
                printf("status of a=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status1));
            }
            if(WIFEXITED(status2)) {
                printf("status of b=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status1));
            }
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        } else {
            perror("second fork failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } else {
        perror("first fork failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

A test program to be called (a and b) could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   if(argc > 0) { 
       printf("%s executing...\n", argv[0]);
   }
   sleep(3);
   if(argc > 0) {
       printf("%s about to finish\n", argv[0]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Calling the test program would produce the following output:

```
./b executing...
./a executing...
./a about to finish
./b about to finish
status of a=0
status of b=0
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether these 2 programs need to interact.

If A and B just have to run at the same time without knowing each other, just start them from a third program C (which may be a bash script).

If A and B need to know each other, e.g. A has to wait at some point for B to finish, use fork(), exec(), wait(). Same applies when one of them needs to stop the other one using kill(). For all these scenarios they have to know the other process's PID which is provided by fork() for A and getppid() for B.

Comment: fork() and exec() do not know the concept of "windows", they just know about processes. Whether processes - once they are started - display something rectangular on a screen is up to them.